# How to skip showing the first item in the ItemsSource that bound with a ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using ItemsControl to show a list of objects. Is it possible, not to show first item of the list ?
I tried creating a new property in my ViewModel which will skip the first element.

```
public ObservableCollection<ConditionElement> ExtraConditionLiteral
{
    get 
    { 
        return ConditionElementList.Skip(0) as ObservableCollection<ConditionElement>; 
    }
}
```

But this is not working.
Is there any way Ican skip the first element while binding with ItemsSource ?

Comment: Well ... forget about the skip first. Can you property even populate anything to GUI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you doesn't skip the element actually. You should pass the count of shipped elements instead of the index.

Try this:

```
return new ObservableCollection<ConditionElement>(ConditionElementList.Skip(1));
```

But you should pay an attention to order of your collection as well.

[Enumerable.Skip Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I did bind this new Properrty to ItemsSource and Nothing is showing

Comment: Skip(1) should be fine. But cast to ObservableCollection should be removed. Skip returns an IEnumerable<T>. So the cast returns null. If you still want an ObservableCollection, you should make a copy of all elements minus 1, in another ObservableCollection . And to keep both collection in synchronization, you should subscribe to the ObservableCollections

Answer (score 1):

I may provide another idea.
You can write your itemscontrol's item template like

```
<Label Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData},Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

So for the first element, the previous element is null, and you need to implement the NullToVisibilityConverter to return Visibility.Collapsed when input is null. I think this Converter is very common.

Comment: How do I get PreviousData ?

Comment: You don't need to get it, it's something like TemplateParent. WPF can parse it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The input param of Skip in LINQ is actually a "Count"
Skip(0) actually telling the LINQ to do nothing at all.

Try Skip(1)